# How to get puppet module's version

Tags: ruby, puppet

I would like to retrieve a module's version through Puppet.

For example:

```
notify { "module version is $module_version": }
```

but this is not possible with Puppet. That's why I would like to add a custom resource or function using Ruby which can handle that.

My idea is to use Ruby to open the `metadata.json`, get the module's version, and add it to the facts. Do you think it's possible to open the `metadata.json` of the module in question? Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `load_module_metadata` function from `stdlib` to accomplish this: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#load_module_metadata

For example, to achieve what you are looking for in your example snippet above, you would do:

```
$metadata = load_module_metadata('module_name')
notify { "module version is ${metadata['version']}": }
```

Note that the return value of `load_module_metadata` will be a hash with strings for keys and values, so use the corresponding hash lookup structure in Puppet accordingly (`$hash_name['hash_key']` returns the corresponding string value for the key).